# AWS lex bot...created "slottypes" like "coffetype" "coffeesize" but can't use them in the bot creation

Tags: amazon-lex

In the construction of the bot, I should be able access the slotypes I created. but I can't see them. There are videos that they we can create slot types and use them in building intents. Even though my slot type exists I can't access them while I am building the Utterances

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reference the slot types within an intent's utterances, you need to have added those slot types to slots within the intent.

Please take a look at this example where I have a slot called `quantity` of type `AMAZON.Number`. I can then reference the `quantity` slot within any utterance that I have.

[image]

Comment: Still unable to find out...Say I want a slot type called "CoffeeType" and the values in that slot should be "Regular coffee", "Mocha" , "Indiancoffee" the user of the bot. Older version of lex bot videos are so easy to use. Later version of Lex  are so complicated. OMG

Answer (score 1):

Reegz's answer was very good and seemed to cover everything so I apologize if I am repeating things.

You've created your own custom slots already, however, you *must* include them in the intent you want to use them with.
You must do this before you add them to Utterances. Otherwise they will not appear in the drop-down.

Add the slots to the intent by going to the **Slots** section of your intent:

[image: Image of Lex V2 Slots section]

Click on the **Add slot** button on the top right corner of this section.

Create a name for the slot, this is similar to setting a variable name for an object. This name is also how you will access the **Slot**.
[image: Image of creating a new slot]

You may need to click save on the intent in order to see changes in the slot drop-down.

Now when you go to add a new Utterance, your custom slot should appear:
[image: Custom slot in drop down]

Let me know if you have anymore questions. I hope this helps you.